# Can not open a file when traversing a symlinked directory

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, symbolic-link, nginx

Nginx is failing to start with the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] ModSecurityConfig in /usr/local/server/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:133: Cannot open config file: /usr/local/server/nginx/conf/../base/base.conf
```

The config is specified like so in the `http{}` block:

```
ModSecurityConfig ../base/base.conf;
```

Additionally the conf direcoty is a symbolic link to `/vagrant/conf/` folder:

```
vagrant@node3:/usr/local/server/nginx$ ls -laht
total 68K
drwxr-xr-x 16 serv    serv    4.0K Oct  7 02:12 .
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root      14 Oct  7 02:12 conf -> /vagrant/conf/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root    4.0K Oct  6 09:17 logs
drwxr-xr-x  2 serv    serv    4.0K Oct  6 09:17 sbin
drwxr-xr-x  2 serv    serv    4.0K Apr 12 09:24 base <<-- the base folder is here
```

This is another interesting behavior, I believe related to nginx not being able to read the files it needs.

```
vagrant@node3:/usr/local/server/nginx/base$ head -n1 /usr/local/server/nginx/conf/../base/base.conf
head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/server/nginx/conf/../base/base.conf’ for reading: No such file or directory
vagrant@node3:/usr/local/server/nginx/base$ cd /usr/local/server/nginx/conf/../base/
vagrant@node3:/usr/local/server/nginx/base$ head -n1 base.conf
### BLAH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gotta love symbolic links.

When you use them, it's simply a shortcut to a new directory structure, and of course /vagrant/base (/vagrant/conf/../base) doesn't exist.

```
cd /vagrant/conf
ln -s /usr/local/server/nginx/base base
```

change your base.conf file location to just "base/base.conf" minus the quotes.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I though about this, but did not think to test it, unfortunately. I simply could have tried to access the folders in /vagrant/ directory after following the symlink. Well that's what the end of the workday sometimes does for you.